# How can I rename my characters?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've noticed that people are able to give their characters custom names, but I haven't been able to find any method to do so in-game. Do I need to unlock it, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `Rogue Legacy/Content` folder, there are two files, `HeroNames.txt` and `HeroineNames.txt`. You can edit these so that the names generated for your characters are whatever you wish, up to 8 letters long.